# Alamofire: cannot invoke download

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm updating a project from Swift 1.2 to 2.0 and I'm having some trouble with Alamofire.download.

Originally I was calling `self.request = Alamofire.download(.GET, self.arquivo!.url, { _ in arquivoPath }).response({ (_, _, _, _) -> Void in`
And I get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on Swift 2.

If I change it to `self.request = Alamofire.download(Method.GET, self.arquivo!.url, { _ in arquivoPath })` I get "Cannot invoke 'download' with argument list of type '(Method, String, (_) -> NSURL)'"

And I can't get it to work with any combination of types.

Answer (score 0):

The `download` closure has two parameters:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, url) { (temporaryURL, response) -> NSURL in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = try! fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}
```

You just have a closure in which defines the file URL of where the downloaded file should be saved.

If you want to detect/handle errors, add a `response` call:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, url) { (temporaryURL, response) -> NSURL in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = try! fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}.response { _, response, _, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("failed with error: \(error)")
    } else if let statusCode = response?.statusCode where statusCode != 200 {
        print("unsuccessful with statusCode: \(statusCode)")
    } else {
        print("download succeeded")
    }
}
```

Obviously, build the URL of where the file should be saved any way you want, but this illustrates the idea.